# meanable groups

Tags: group-theory

Suppose that the countable group $G$ has a left invariant mean on $l^\infty \left(G\right)$ , $L_l$ , and suppose that $G$ has a right invariant mean on $l^\infty \left(G\right)$ , $L_r$.

Please show that $G$ has a conjugation invariant mean.

I know that exists an isomorphism $\phi:G\rightarrow G$ such that for every $g\in G$ if we denote $l_g:G\rightarrow G$ by $l_g(h)=gh$ and we denote $r_g:G\rightarrow G$ by $r_g(h)=hg$ so we get $\phi\circ l_g = r_g \circ \phi$.

I tried to build $L_c$ (the c is for conjugation) the functions:

1. $\frac {1}{2} \left(L_l+L_r \right)$
2. $\frac {1}{2} \left(L_l\circ \phi+L_r \circ \phi^{-1} \right)$

They both doesn't satisfy (at least I didn't manage to prove) that for every $c_g:G\rightarrow G$ by $c_g(h)=ghg^{-1}$ and for every bounded $f:G\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$  we get $L_c \left(f\circ c_g\right)=L_c(f)$.

Can someone light me up? or maybe I'm in the wrong way at all. any help would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume a *mean* is a linear functional $l^\infty(G)\to\bf R$? I'm not actually familiar with the term.

However two thoughts occur to me:

- $L_l$ is $l_g$-invariant, but how does it behave under $r_g$-action?
- The $L$s cannot be applied to each other; what if we reinterpret $L$ as a function of $G$?

These led me to pursue $L_c:f\mapsto L_r(g\mapsto L_l(f\circ r_g))$. Since

$$c_h\circ r_g\,(x)=hxgh^{-1}=r_{gh^{-1}}\circ l_h\,(x)$$

we deduce

$$\begin{array}{ll} L_c\circ c_h\,(f) & =L_r(g\mapsto L_l((f\circ c_h)\circ r_g)) \\ & = L_r(g\mapsto L_l((f\circ r_{gh^{-1}})\circ l_h)) \\ & = L_r(g\mapsto L_l(f\circ r_{gh^{-1}})) \\ & = L_r((g\mapsto L_l(f\circ r_g))\circ r_{h^{-1}}) \\ & = L_r(g\mapsto L_l(f\circ r_g)) \\ & = L_c(f).\end{array}$$

It's fairly likely I've made a mistake, though, given the large number of layers deep we are into composition of functions and operators (I can see diCaprio squinting at me as I type).

Comment: @user2359227 Given a function $f$, the expression $g\mapsto L_l(f\circ r_g)$ is a function of $g$, and we can apply the operator $L_r$ to functions of $g$. To abuse the integral symbol, one way of thinking about this is $$L_c(f):=\overset{\rm right}{\int_G}\overset{\rm left}{\int_G} f(uv)\,{\rm d}u\,{\rm d}v.$$

Comment: Can you explain the equality: $L_r\left( g\mapsto L_l\left( f \circ r_{gh^{-1}} \right) \right) = L_r\left( g\mapsto L_l\left( f \circ r_{g} \right) \circ r_h^{-1} \right)$

Comment: @user2359227 Precomposing $g\mapsto L_l(f\circ r_g)$ with $r_{h^{-1}}$ should send $g$ to where the original map would send $gh^{-1}$, i.e. to $L_l(f\circ r_{gh^{-1}})$.